Passing the value from a sum to variable returns zero while passing the same sum to a Range gives the value
I want to add 2 specific cells and to a variable to use that sum later but it is coming out with a zero value. However if I do the same sum and pass to a range/cell then it works as expected. The values in the cells are whole numbers. I have tried Long/Integer/Double
The code is
sub test()
Dim total as Long
total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2,3),Cells(3,8))
Range("D50") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2,3),Cells(3,8))
End Sub

So for Total it shows zero but range is 30 as expected

You have an issue the scope of the variable.
The variable total is for sure calculated correctly (check with the debugger!), but the variable is known only inside the routine and once the routine is finished, the value is gone.
If you write
Sub testOuter
   Call test
   Debug.Print total       ' Will print 0 
End Sub

total is a different variable, only with the same name.
You could change that behavior by using a global variable, but don't do that, globals should be avoided:
Dim total As Long       ' This variable is valid for all routines in this module

Sub testOuter
   Call test
   Debug.Print total    ' Will print the Sum calculated in test
End Sub

Sub test()              
    ' Don't declare total here, or you have another variable with the same name
    total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2,3),Cells(3,8))
End Sub

In your case, probably it's best to change the routine to a function:
Sub testOuter
   Dim total As long
   total = calcTotal
   Debug.Print total    ' Will print the Sum calculated in test
End Sub

Function calcTotal() As Long
    calcTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2,3),Cells(3,8))
End Function 


Thanks. I am looking to loop the sum through the spreadsheet so it is something like
For i = 2 to 10
For j = 2 to 10
Total = Sum(Cells(i.j),Cells(i+1,j+1))
next j
next i
So that I can use each value of total to see if it is higher or Lower than another value.
So I am not sure if these will work but I will give it a go
